# String Reversal using Recurrsion using char*

Tags: arrays, pointers, recursion, char, reverse

I want string reversed in-place using Recursion. Though this might be duplicate question but I don't understand error in my code below and I searched for answers before asking here.

```
#include "Reversal.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int size = 10;
char* Reversal :: rever (char *str, int i, int j)
{
    if (i>=j)
        return str;
    char a;
    a = str[i];
    str[i] = str[j];
    str[j] = a;

    rever(str, i+1, j-1);
}

int main()
{
    Reversal obj;
    char *ptr = new char[size];
    char *reverse = new char[size];
    cout << " Enter a string \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < size-1; i++)
    {
        cin >> ptr[i];
    }

    reverse = obj.rever(ptr, 0, strlen(ptr)-1);

    for (int k = 0; k < strlen(reverse)-1; k++)
    {
        cout << reverse[k];
    }
    return 0;

}
```

and Reversal.h file is

```
#ifndef REVERSAL_H_
#define REVERSAL_H_

class Reversal {
public:
    Reversal();
    char* rever(char*, int,int);
    virtual ~Reversal();
};

#endif /* REVERSAL_H_ */
```

Comment: What problem did you faced? Is it not reversing string correctly ?? Or, something else ?

Comment: Error is :
  "Reversal::~Reversal()", referenced from:
      _main in Reversal.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [String_rever_recurr] Error 1

Comment: I am using eclipse on mac machine

Answer (score 0):

This code has quite a few problems.  The first thing you need to decide is whether you are reversing your input string in place, or returning a pointer to a newly allocated string.  Since it looks like you planned on filling a second array, let's stick with that:

```
void Reversal::rever(char* buf, char* str, int i, int j)
{
    if (i>=j)
    {
        buf[strlen(str)] = '\0';
        return;
    }
    buf[j] = str[i];
    buf[i] = str[j];

    rever(buf, str, i+1, j-1);
}
```

Called as:

```
obj.rever(reverse, str, 0, strlen(str)-1);
```

Note that I would not make this part of a class unless there is some other reason to do so (like if it were instead to return the reverse of a `char*` contained in the class), and since we are using C++ I would recommend using `std::string` instead of `char*`.

Comment: this worked fine but error was : I was not defining constructor and Destructor. I declared in .h file but forgot to define. I did that and it worked. Thank you for rectification :)